# Geoserver envelope function not working in YSLD

Tags: geoserver, sld, ysld

I'm trying to use `envelope` function like this i my ysld:

```
- line:
    uom: metre
    geometry: ${envelope(geometry)}
```

My ysld won't validate with error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid cql expression 'envelope(geometry)'
```

Functions: `convexHull`, `boundary` or even `octagonalenvelope` found on https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/function_list.html works well. 
`envelope` and `octagonalenvelope` definitions are very similar but still `envelope` doesn't work in ysld. I'm using Geoserver 2.16.2

```
envelope(geom): returns result
geom (Geometry) required

result (Geometry)



octagonalEnvelope(geom): returns result
geom (Geometry) required

result (Geometry)
```

Relevant log file part exceeded character body limit. Log file part available [here](https://textuploader.com/1cn0v)

```
Caused by: org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQLException: Encountered "geometry" at line 1, column 10.
Was expecting one of:
    "-" ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_LITERAL> ...
     Parsing : envelope(geometry).
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQLCompiler.compileExpression(ECQLCompiler.java:99)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.commons.CompilerUtil.parseExpression(CompilerUtil.java:172)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL.toExpression(ECQL.java:144)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL.toExpression(ECQL.java:125)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.ExpressionExtractor.splitCqlExpressions(ExpressionExtractor.java:111)
    ... 140 more
```

Comment: please look in the geoserver log file and [edit] the question to add the relevant part

Comment: This works if I use plain SLD so it may be an YSLD issue

Comment: I've updated my post with relevant log file part.

Comment: If this looks like a YSLD bug where can I post a ticket?

Comment: see http://geoserver.org/comm/ and http://geoserver.org/issues/